# Changing the value of a select option value when the value is a string and not a int

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change the value of a select when the value of the option is a string? Doesn't seem to work.

```
<select class="value1">
    <option value="=">Equal To</option>
</select>

$('.value1').val('=').change();
```

Comment: All attribute values are strings.

Comment: Should this work?

Comment: There is only one data type in H**T**ML. String.

Comment: You have an unwanted `<` character before `Equal To`. Or you want to htmlencode it (`&lt;`).

Comment: that was just a mistake in writing

Comment: It should work, no need to call `change()` btw (unless you want to trigger a handler manually, in which case `.trigger('change')` is more jQuery-ish).

Comment: @CesarBielich It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/jyma4b0s/. Do you have a specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the call to the `.change()` method (which effectively invokes the `change` event) unless there's more to your use case than you are showing and asking about here.

Just update the `.val()` to modify the element's `value`. Now, to be clear, your `<select>` (as you've written it) will already have a value of `=` because there is only one `<option>` in the list and that `option` already has `=` set statically for its value.

```js
// Because you only have one <option> in the list, that <option>
// becomes the default and it already has a value of "=", so we
// really don't need to do anything to get the <select> to take
// on the value of its only <option>
console.log("Default value of the select is: " + $('.value1').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="value1">
    <option value="=">Equal To</option>
</select>
```

**But, understand that the `value` is not the same thing as what is shown in the dropdown as choices.** The `<select>` element's `value` is the value that the element currently is storing in memory. What's in memory is not the same thing as what's displayed in the drop down list.

For that, you have to modify the `.text()` of the corresponding `option` element.

```js
// To change what is shown in the drop down, you have
// to modify the corresponding <option> element's text
$('.value1 > option').text('=');
console.log("The <select> element's value is: " + $('.value1').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="value1">
    <option value="=">Equal To</option>
</select>
```

And lastly, putting it all together with a more realistic list:

```js
// Start with the default value of the <select>, 
// which, by default, is the value of the first <option>
console.log("Initial (default) value of the <select> is: " + $('.value1').val());

// Change the <select> value to something else, but it must be one
// of the values defined for one of the <option> elements. This will
// cause that option to become selected and shown in the list
$('.value1').val('>');
console.log("Current value of the <select> is now: " + $('.value1').val());

// Modify the text that corresponds to one of the <option> elements
$('.value1 > option:nth-child(2)').text('< Than');

// But changing the text doesn't change the underlying value of that <option>
console.log("<option>'s value is: " + $('.value1 > option:nth-child(2)').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="value1">
    <option value="=">Equal To</option>
    <option value="<">Less Than</option>
    <option value=">">Greater Than</option>
    <option value="<=">Less Than or Equal To</option>    
    <option value=">=">Greater Than or Equal To</option>      
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you could use is to set the `selectedIndex` property of the select.

```js
var $select = $('.value1');
var $targetOption = $select.find('option').filter(function(){
  return this.value === '>';
});

$select.prop('selectedIndex', $targetOption.index());
console.log($select.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="value1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="=">Equal To</option>
    <option value=">">Greater Than</option>
    <option value="<">Less Than</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow, that's an extremely verbose way to write `$(".value1 option[value='>']").index()`

Comment: I like to avoid the sizzle engine as much as possible. @Barmar